# After apply function spark rdd todf error (python-spark)?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I want to apply some function on df column by using spark.
But i can not convert rdd to todf. How can i solve this problem?

I tried following code;

**data** is pandas dataframe

```
#some function (example)
def replacament(row):
    
    text = row['METIN']
    text = unicode_tr(text).lower()
    return text

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([StructField('METIN',StringType())])
s_df = spark.createDataFrame(data[['METIN']], schema)

new_rdd = s_df.rdd.map(replacament)
df_rdd = new_rdd.toDF(s_df.columns+['METIN2'])
```

RuntimeError: SparkContext or SparkSession should be created first.

Comment: Hello and welcome, please indicate what you have tried t solve this issue. There seems to be a wealth of documentation about creating such sessions. Has nothing helped?

Answer (score 0):

Using RDD transformations for row-wise operations might not be as efficient as using Spark's built-in DataFrame operations
or User-Defined Functions (UDFs). The DataFrame API is optimized for data processing tasks
and can take advantage of Spark's Catalyst optimizer,
whereas using RDDs directly skips these optimizations.

Therefore, DataFrame operations are generally more performant
and should be preferred when possible.

You can create a UDF function to do this transformation like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Initialize Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("udf example") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Your replacement function 
def replacament(text):
    # Assuming unicode_tr is defined elsewhere
    text = unicode_tr(text).lower()
    return text

# Register the UDF
udf_replacament = udf(replacament, StringType())

# Create DataFrame from Pandas DataFrame
schema = StringType()
s_df = spark.createDataFrame(data[['METIN']], schema=schema)

# Apply the UDF
new_df = s_df.withColumn("METIN2", udf_replacament("METIN"))
```

In case you want to use the RDD interface nevertheless your code contains a mistake.

In your code, `new_rdd.toDF(s_df.columns+['METIN2'])` assumes that the RDD new_rdd contains Row objects  with the names you've specified, but this is not the case.

The RDD contains just the transformed text,
so you can't convert it back to a DataFrame with a schema that matches the original one. So you would need basically to change what your function returns. So it would need to be like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Initialize Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("RDD example") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([StructField('METIN', StringType())])

# Create a Spark DataFrame from the Pandas DataFrame
s_df = spark.createDataFrame(data[['METIN']], schema=schema)

# Define a transformation function
def replacament(row):
    text = row.METIN
    # Assuming unicode_tr is defined elsewhere
    text = unicode_tr(text).lower()
    return Row(METIN=text, METIN2=text)  # return Row object

# Transform the DataFrame to RDD and apply the function
new_rdd = s_df.rdd.map(replacament)

# Convert the RDD back to DataFrame
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_rdd, ["METIN", "METIN2"])
```

Comment: Does not skip, they are simply not there.

Comment: @thebluephantom what do you mean? cannot understand your comment

Comment: First i want to thank you for your answer, The code gives this error for last line ; A column or function parameter with name `METIN` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`value`].;
'Project [value#1129, replacament('METIN)#1131 AS METIN2#1132] @mamonu

Comment: second one is working, thanks a lot

Comment: If you think this answered your question please accept it :)